# Prove that there is no convex polyhedron

Tags: solid-geometry

> Prove that there is no convex polyhedron with exactly $7$ edges

**Solution:** We show first that for any polyhedron we have $2E \geq 3F$ and $2E \geq 3V$. The faces of the polyhedron are polygons, each bounded by a number of sides. Along each edge exactly two faces come together, so an edge corresponds to exactly two sides: the total number of sides is $2E$. We also notice that any face has at least $3$ sides, so the total number of sides is at least $3$ times the number of faces. Thus we get:

The total number of sides = $2E$

and

The total number of sides $\geq 3F$.

Putting this together we get:

$2E \geq 3F$,

proving our first inequality.

To prove the second inequality we count the total number of ends of edges. Each edge has two ends, so the total number of ends equals $2E$. At each vertex at least three edges come together, so the total number of ends of edges is at least $3$ times the number of vertices. Putting this together we get:

$2E \geq 3V$.

Now, if a polyhedron has $7$ edges, then $3F \leq 14$ and $3V \leq 14$. This means that both $F$ and $V$ cannot be bigger than $4$. A little thought will convince you that every polyhedron has strictly more than three faces, so we must have $F=4$. Similarly we get that $V=4$. This gives

$$V - E + F = 4 - 7 + 4 = 1 \neq 2$$.

This tells us that our hypothetical seven-edged polyhedron cannot exist, for if it did, then Euler's formula would hold and the above sum would have to be equal to $2$

**Question:** Are there any more formal or shorter demonstrations than this? If not, how to proceed with a different solution?

Comment: In what way do you think your solution isn't formal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the Euler theorem is not required. Since you found $V=4$, the polyhedron is necessarily a tetrahedron(and this can be proved easily by exhaustion). This procedure is more general, because it removes the convexity hyphothesis.

There are no polyhedron with 7 edges.

Even more generally you can prove easily that there exist polyhedron with $n$ edges with n≥6, with 7 being the only exception.